# Array behaves very weirdly in C?

Tags: javascript, c, arrays

Here's the code to delete the **first element** of the array:

```
int main()
{
        int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
        int newArr[5] ={};
        for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++){
            newArr[i] = arr[i];
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            printf("%d, ", newArr[i]);
        }

    return 0;
}
```

The result is :  `0,2,3,4`

I tried to `printf` in the first for loop. Each prints `2,3,4,5`, respectively

I don't understand why it misses the number 5.

I tried with Javascript and it works normally :

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
let newArr = [];
for(let i = 1; i < 5; i++){
    newArr.push(arr[i]);
};
for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    console.log(newArr[i], ",");
}
```

**PLEASE HELP!**

Comment: Look at your second loop. What's the highest index that you go to? What's the index of the `5`?

Comment: The highest index is 3

Comment: The first loop stores `5` at index `4` though, then the second loop only goes to index `3`. You're simply ignoring the last element in the second loop.

Comment: Ohhh okay. Thank you Carci. I get it now

Comment: It's because you're storing the numbers in the same position in both arrays. If you want to remove the first number, the `2` needs to be stored at index `0` in the second array, and the `3` at index `1`...

Comment: Unrelated: `int a[5] = {};` is not Standard C. To guarantee your code compiles in any Standard compliant compiler (with or without extensions) use `int a[5] = {0};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here in code, even u want to `remove 1` element but you are creating an element of `5`. and you start adding element form `position 1`, not the `zero`. By default `c int value` is `0`. So you don't get an error when u print form`0-4`

You can fix code like as below given.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
        int newArr[4];
        for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++){
            newArr[i-1] = arr[i];
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            printf("%d, ", newArr[i]);
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It misses the number 5 because your second for-loop only runs 4 times, `for  i = 0, 1, 2, 3`. Then `i` becomes 4 and for loop terminates, without printing `newArr[4]`.

You can use debugger to step one command at a time and see what the problem is.

To fix the problem - change the bound for the second for-loop to be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   printf("%d, ", newArr[i]);
}
```